# Android Studio:Need help in IntentFilter

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm doing a small program in android studio and I need help in this code:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotifyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    BroadReceiver receiver = new BroadReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("I NEED HELP HERE!");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
```

So, in the line **I NEED HELP HERE**, when I wrote `Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED` it runs like it should be, but I need the code above to do the function of the `ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED`. Basically, every fifteen minutes the background program (this code is there) should open a notification.

If you need more code just say.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. `AlramManager`'s `PendingIntent` contains `Intent` which will be fired when the alarm is fired. So, you should change:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotifyService.class);
```

to this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , BroadReceiver.class);
```

Here you can find more detailed examples
[Google's alarm guide](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

If you want to use implicit intent, then you can try like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setAction("your_action");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

// setup AlarmManager

BroadReceiver receiver = new BroadReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("your_action");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Comment: But I don't want a action, what I want is the code above to work like an action.

Comment: Basically, all the code above the BroadReceiver receiver = new BroadReceiver(); is doing nothing if I don't call him in registerReceiver(receiver, filter); because the class BroadcastReceiver it is the one that I have the code to send the notification. The class that I am showing you is the Service class.

Comment: I can now run the code above, by changing PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0); to PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);     Now I need to repeat the code every fifteen minute and the code don't do that.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get the concept. Android is event-based system and AlarmManager will notify receiver. Intent may be Explicit and will call exact component or may be implicit and will call all the components available for this action. Thus you subclass BroadcastReceiver, register it (i suggest using manifest for that) and consctruct proper intent. Of course this code will not repeat every 15 mins, because AlarmManager fires intent that will call NotifyService class.